# Jenkins Rally Plugin failure

Tags: jenkins, rally

I have just installed combo Jenkins, Rally, Github, eclipse all interconnected down to the last connection Rally Jenkins but I get the following error on the console at the end of the build

```
Updating Rally -- Louis # US98 Test 31 (31)
    rally update plug-in error: could not update changeset entry: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:422)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doRequest(RallyRestApi.java:310)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doForceReauthRequest(RallyRestApi.java:332)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doGet(RallyRestApi.java:460)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.get(RallyRestApi.java:266)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.attachSecurityInfo(RallyRestApi.java:373)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doSecuredRequest(RallyRestApi.java:350)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.doPost(RallyRestApi.java:417)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.create(RallyRestApi.java:169)
    at com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi.create(RallyRestApi.java:165)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.createDefaultPluginSCMReposirotyName(RallyConnector.java:263)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.getSCMRepoName(RallyConnector.java:203)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.createSCMRef(RallyConnector.java:185)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.createChangeSet(RallyConnector.java:74)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.connector.RallyConnector.updateRallyChangeSet(RallyConnector.java:58)
    at com.jenkins.plugins.rally.PostBuild.perform(PostBuild.java:82)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:772)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:535)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1732)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:234)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My Plugin setup in my project is as:

- User Name: `Jenkins@mycomapny`
- Password: `*******`
- Rally Workspace: `Workspace 1`
- Rally Project: `Version1`
- SCM URI: `left Blank`
- CM Repository Name: `Left Blank`
- Update Changes: `Since last build`
- Changes start date: `left blank`
- Changes end Date: `Left blank`
- Turn on debug level: `not selected`

I am trying to get the result of the build back into Rally.

Any help appreciated. This is my first post comments welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a call from Rally, they apparently purposefully block the connector from working with the community version.  Caveat Emptor